# jquery - getting every p element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to grab every p element inside my jquery object but for some reason I'm only getting an empty variable.

```
var content = "";       
$newFeed.find("p").each(function(index, element) {
content += $(this).html();  });
```

If I change `("p")` to any other element, say `div`, then I would get every div element but not any `p`. I've tried both `$(this).html()` and `$(this).text()`

Comment: can you show us the content of `newFeed`, may be `$newFeed.filter("p")`

Comment: plz add your html also in que..!

Comment: Working fine with `$(this).text()`. http://jsfiddle.net/MQQEv/ Can you show us the content of `newFeed`?

Comment: unless we know what is there in `$newFeed` we won't be able to help you much...

Comment: My HTML comes dynamically from the server and it's full of crap. here's a screenshot http://i.imgur.com/q9JrHNW.png

Comment: how is the variable `$newFeed` defined...

Comment: It comes from a json feed. http://www.budgetbytes.com/api/get_post/?post_id=19381

Comment: @Keivan did you try the `.filter('p')` option as I suggested.. are you doing something like `$newFeed = $(content-from-rss-feed)`

Comment: ok `filter('p)` works now. with `.text()` thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for

```
    <div id = "parent">
      <p> elem1</p>
      <p> elem2</p>
      <p> elem3</p>
   </div>
   <div id = "parent1">
      <p> elem11</p>
      <p> elem22</p>
      <p> elem33</p>
   </div>
```

Jquery

```
    $("p").each(function(e){
       alert($(this).text());
    });
```

Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/AmarnathRShenoy/ByVT9/